# Query a association property when you only know the string name of that property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a entity framework class A.  It has a 1 to many relationship with B.  The property name of this relationship in A is AtoB.

At runtime if I am given a string of "AtoB" is there a way to issue a linq query to A on the AtoB property to get a list of all the B's associated with that A?

So basically I won't know until runtime what property on A that I should be running a linq query on.

```
// Pseudo code
int id = GetID();
string tableName = GetTableName();
var v = context.[tableName].Where(t => t.ID == id);
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive with sample code if possible. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve? Loading navigation property? `context.Departments.Include("Courses")`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dynamic Linq](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com) to execute a string Linq query - just embed the name of the property into the string where appropriate.